# C# winforms mvp show child form in presenter

Tags: c#, winforms, mvp

I have using MVP design patern and i `MainForm(MDI)` i want to show child forms inside parent mdi container.

**My question is:**

Is good practice to put code for initializing child form inside `view` or `presenter`?

Mehtod from view which call presenter method `ShowMusicLibrary`:

**View**

```
public void ShowLibraryButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Presenter.ShowMusicLibrary();

    // put here or in presenter
}
```

**Presenter:**

```
    public void ShowMusicLibrary()
    {
        this._model.ShowAll();
    }
```

**Code for initializing child form is here :**

```
 foreach (Form topList in Application.OpenForms)
 {
     if (topList.GetType() == typeof(MusicLibrary))
     {
          form.Activate();
          return;
     }

     _ms = new MusicLibrary();
     _ms.MdiParent = this;
     _ms.Show(); 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MVP patern then show child form in Presenter. 
It's the best solution.
Don't call presenter direcly like

```
  this.Presenter.ShowMusicLibrary();
```

Create interface with event that will be implemented on presenter and will called when yotu are going to show child view after clicking button on view. 
Somethink like that:

```
intercafe IShowMusicLibrary
{
event action show();
}

//view


public void ShowLibraryButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(show!=null)
show();


}

//presenter
private IShowMusicLibrary _musicLibrary;

// in constructor
_musicLibrary.show += YourEvent;


public YourEvent()
{
//here show a child control.
}
```